# Automatically copy a file from one GitHub repository to another via Codehip

Tags: github, webhooks, codeship

I have two repositories: `S1`, `S2`

I would like to automatically push a file from `S1` to `S2` if it is changed or created.

**For example:**

I push `translation.en.json` to `/translations/translation.en.json` in `S1`.
`translation.en.json` should automatically pushed to `/dashboard/translation.en.json` in `S2`.

When I push something to master branch in `S1` then the codeship build will be run.

I want to write a script in `codeship` steps which can do this automatic push.

*I tried something like this:*

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
mkdir -p _translations/dashboard/
cd _translations
git fetch --unshallow || true
git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
git push git@github.com:company/translations.git "${CI_COMMIT_ID}:master"
```

Comment: I wrote up a possible workflow based on your question, but since you mentioned you tried the above script it would be helpful to know what worked and what didn't work as well. Also, feel free to reach out to the Codeship Support (of which I'm a member) via https://helpdesk.codeship.com as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a script based deployment for pushing to a different git repository available at https://github.com/codeship/scripts/blob/master/deployments/git_push.sh

You can add that to your deployment pipeline by adding a *Script Deployment* by setting the required environment variables and adding the `curl` command, e.g.

```
export REMOTE_REPOSITORY="git@github.com:company/s2.git"
export REMOTE_BRANCH="master"
\curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeship/scripts/master/deployments/git_push.sh | bash -s
```

You will also need to make sure that the Codeship projects SSH key (available via the project settings) is allowed to push to the second repository. See https://documentation.codeship.com/general/projects/access-to-other-repositories-fails-during-build/ for how to configure this.

However, this will push the complete contents for `S1` to the other repository. If you only want to push a specific file (or a set of files) I'd recommend cloning the second repository, copying the files over and then committing and pushing. A sample script could look like this:

```
cd "${HOME}"
git clone git@github.com:company/s2.git
# "${HOME}/clone" is the default checkout path on Codeship
cp ./clone/translation.en.json ./s2/
cd ./s2
git commit -a "Automatic commit, based on "company/s1@${CI_COMMIT_ID}"
git push origin master
```

Please note, that this script is not tested and definitely needs to be adapted to your specific needs. The note regarding authentication and access to the second repository applies to this use case as well.